# Android - Exoplayer shows blank screen instead of Playing video

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to integrate Exoplayer library to my android app.

Below are the following code i have implemented in android app.

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ayalus.exoplayer2example.MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resolution_textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ayalus.exoplayer2example;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Format;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.decoder.DecoderCounters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.LoopingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoRendererEventListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private PlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private TextView resolutionTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resolutionTextView = new TextView(this);
        resolutionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resolution_textView);




Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://live.field59.com/wwsb/ngrp:wwsb1_all/playlist.m3u8");
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(); //test

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        int h = simpleExoPlayerView.getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
        int w = simpleExoPlayerView.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
        Log.v(TAG, "height : " + h + " weight: " + w);
        ////Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);//set to true or false to see controllers
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
        player.setVideoDebugListener(this);
    }
   }
```

I have given internet permision in AndroidManifest.xml.

The Problem is when i run the android app, Instead of playing video, its giving me black screen.

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Can you post log as well when this activity was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think your videoSource is wrong, you should use `videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory` not just `new HlsMediaSource`

could you show us your `dataSourceFactory` as well just in case it's not the `videoSource` the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your below line of code:

```
MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
```

To, (Update below line):

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"), null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);

HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri,dataSourceFactory, 1800000,new Handler(), null);
```

Comment: I am using exoplayer2 when i rotate screen on button click for few second it displayes blank screen like portrait to landscape mode Please help me on this if you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had initialized my exoplayer in oncreateviewholder. Shifting initialization to onbindviewholder fixed the probem in my case:)